# How to use Return data after ajax call success in if statement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have something like this, where it is a simple call to a script that gives me back a value, a string but when i use alert function than it display correct value but after if condition it didn't showing the alert message. I just want to compare the value of data to the value that is coming from login.php.

```
$("#login").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var Email = $("#email").val();
        var Password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "include/login.php",
            method : "POST",
            data : {CustomerLogin:1,CustomerEmail:Email,CustomerPassword:Password},
            success : function(data){
                if(data == 'true'){
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323)

Comment: What do you mean by "after if condition it didn't showing the value"?  There is no code after the `if` block, so what would you *expect* to happen there?

Comment: Is the return data a boolean or string representation of a boolean?

Comment: @Kramb that makes no sense.... all response data is sent as string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: display correct value? what is the value? do you mean you want if(data)?

Comment: @charlietfl He probably meant that he is not getting values outside the ajax call where he might have some statements depending on the returned value.

Comment: @charlietfl I meant the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

you cann't compare boolean with string value . So you need to pass the boolean value for comparison

```js
if(data == true){
    alert(data);
}
            
OR
            
if(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: his problem is he is getting data in alert but as he put true value inside string quotes == is not working .. So it's not going inside if block  .

Comment: The alert is inside the if condition that means the condition evaluates to `true`. So your answer does not really solves the problem

Comment: Do you think 'true' & true both are same ??

Comment: No they are not. But the point is, he said he is already getting the alert.

Comment: let him check once ..it might useful for him

Comment: even he mentioned .. you can see " but after if condition it didn't showing the value."

Comment: that means before if .. he might use alert to see the value ..@a

Comment: Maybe you are right but his question is poorly worded. Edit your answer a bit with some explanation.

Comment: Data ***is a string***!

Comment: yes i have use alert before if condition then it is working but after if condition it is not working. I want to compare the data value to some specific value. After satisfying if condition next code will run otherwise not.

Comment: I want to compare data value with some specific string or integer value.

Comment: then you need to use specific logic for your requirements .. By this it will go inside if block . previously it was not going . I think you are doing ajax call incorrectly . With URL append username ,password & check this in postman or Advanced REST client . if you get acesstoken . then do ajax call set the credentials in localstorage . make another ajax call you may get value as required

Comment: try if (data.CustomerLogin==1)